# Comparing three numbers given by user in C

Tags: c

I was trying to compare three integers equality as three different outputs.
First, all are equal; second, all are different; and third, neither of them. I just tried to do it like that but this code works wrong for some numbers such as 4,5,5 other combinations work fine. How can I resolve the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a,b,c;
    printf("Please enter three numbers:");
    scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);
    if(a==b && b==c) {
        printf("All numbers are equal.");
    } 
    else if(a!=b && b!=c && a!=c) printf("All numbers are different.");
    
    else if(a=b) {
        if(b!=c) printf("Neither all are equal or different.");
    }
    
    else if(a=c) {
        if(c!=b) printf("Neither all are equal or different.");
    }
    else if(b=c) {
        if(b!=a) printf("Neither all are equal or different.");
    }

    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think output should be for 4,5,5 ?

Comment: Thanks a lot didnt even notice.

Comment: It must have been "Neither all are equal or different." in normally but thanks to my typos :) I just fixed it thank you all

Comment: Actually you' re missing another point there it might be all equal but also might be two are equal and last one is different from them. This is why i added last three

Comment: Oh, you meant i could write it shorter as one line yes.Sorry

Comment: else printf("Neither all are equal or different.");

Comment: I did it as this. You meant that I thought. I misunderstood you at first :)

Comment: If the only outputs are "all equal", "all different" and "neither", then you can reduce everything from `else if (a=b) {` (which should be `else if (a==b) {`) onwards to a single `else { printf("Neither all are equal or different."); }`.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the 'typos' in your last three `else if` tests (`=` is an *assignment*, but you need the *comparison* operator, `==`), those three tests are actually unnecessary.

If the first two tests *both* fail, then you *already know* that the third option is the case. So your code can be reduced to something like this:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    printf("Please enter three numbers:");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    if (a == b && b == c) {
        printf("All numbers are equal.");
    }
    else if (a != b && b != c && a != c) {
        printf("All numbers are different.");
    }
    else {
        printf("Neither all are equal nor all are different.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```